# Merging/Multiply missing value in array

Tags: php

I am struggle to find proper logic to merge/multiply string arrays.
Take a look at my example below I have 2 arrays.

First Array:

```
 ["Services"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "Website Service"
    [1]=>
    string(17) "WordPress Service"
  }
```

Second Array:

```
["City"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "New York"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "Los Angeles"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "Chicago"
  }
```

what I want is to merge it like multiply 3*2=6 example:

```
array(6){
    0 =>  [
        "Service" => "Website Service",
        "City" => "New York"
    ],
    1 =>  [
        "Service" => "Website Service",
        "City" => "Los Angeles"
    ],
    2 =>  [
        "Service" => "Website Service",
        "City" => "Chicago"
    ],
    3 =>  [
        "Service" => "Wordpress Service",
        "City" => "New York"
    ],
    4 =>  [
        "Service" => "Wordpress Service",
        "City" => "Chicago"
    ],
    5 =>  [
        "Service" => "Wordpress Service",
        "City" => "Los Angeles"
    ],
}
```

Forget to mention, that array will be dynamic. Not only 2 with current example!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please use `var_export()` next time.

Comment: yea sure, Sorry I got little frustrated :)

Comment: @Dharman yup updated question.

Comment: @Capripio for dynamic input arrays, I have posted an answer where you can add multiple input arrays without adding multiple for loops to get combinations.

Comment: @SatishSaini, Done thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are dynamic input arrays then you need to think of a recursive solution while merging them.

Here is a working solution:

```
// function to make combinations of input arrays
function combinations($arrays) {
    $result = array(array());
    foreach ($arrays as $property => $property_values) {
        $tmp = array();
        foreach ($result as $result_item) {
            foreach ($property_values as $property_value) {
                $tmp[] = array_merge($result_item, array($property => $property_value));
            }
        }
        $result = $tmp;
    }
    return $result;
}
$combinations = combinations(
    array(
        'Services' => array('Website Service', 'Wordpress Service'), // this can be your services array
        'City' => array('New York', 'Chicago', 'Los Angeles'), // cities array
        'Zip' => array('90001', '90002'), // zip array and you can add more next to it
        // add more arrays here 
    )
);

// print all combinations
print_r($combinations);
```

### Here is a [DEMO](https://ideone.com/U5gYSm)

**Tip (adding it because of suggested edits):**

You can also initialize an array like `[]` in PHP 5.4 and higher versions.

Prior to PHP 5.4:

```
$array = array();
```

PHP 5.4 and higher

```
$array = [];
```

There is no difference in overhead because, as far as the compiler/parser is concerned, they are completely synonymous. If you need it to support older versions of PHP, use the former syntax.